# Pandas - Add seconds from a column to datetime in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame with two columns, `["StartDate" ,"duration"]` 
the elements in the `StartDate` column are `datetime` type, and the `duration` are ints.

Something like:

```
StartDate  Duration
08:16:05    20  
07:16:01    20
```

I expect to get:

```
EndDate 
08:16:25
07:16:21
```

Simply add the seconds to the hour.

I'd being checking some ideas about it like the delta [time types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) and that all those datetimes have the possibilities to add delta times, but so far I can find how to do it with the DataFrames (in a vector fashion, cause It might be possible to iterate over all the rows performing the operation ).

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output to this question

Answer (score 36, accepted):

consider this df

```
    StartDate   duration
0   01/01/2017  135
1   01/02/2017  235
```

You can get the datetime column like this

```
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='s')
df.drop('StartDate,'duration', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

You get

```
    EndDate             
0   2017-01-01 00:02:15 
1   2017-01-02 00:03:55
```

EDIT: with the sample dataframe that you posted

```
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['StartDate']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'], unit='s')
```

Comment: Hi. I get this erro when i try this "TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood" the problem is when i try to add the timedeltas.

Comment: Yeah, I try using the timedelta insted of datetime.

Comment: If i perform pd.to_timedelta(df['StartDate']) or pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'], unit='s') separately i get no error, but when i try to add them, it give that type error.

Comment: Apparently the issue is already reported and can be solved by updating pandas. What version are you using? I am using '0.19.2' and the solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.StartDate = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.StartDate)+pd.Timedelta(Second(df.duration)) ,axis = 1)
```

Comment: What's `Second` ?