# Change value of datetime in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

i want to change the value of a pandas dataframe column with datetime format.
Basically i want to add always 20 seconds to a row. Im new to python/pandas so i dont know any ways to solve that issue.

Here is my code so far:

```py
df_date = dataframe['date'] # get date column
df_date = datedf.to_frame() #convert series to df


for index, row in df_date.iterrows():
    if (index % 3 == 0):
        #minute +1 f. e. from 12:00:40 to 12:01:0

    elif (index % 3 == 1) or (index % 3 == 2):     
        # seconds + 20 
        # from 12:01:00 to 12:01:20
        # or from 12:01:20 to 12:01:40
```

Dataframe df_date:
original:

```
0  2017-03-10 01:00:00
1  2017-03-10 01:00:00
2  2017-03-10 01:00:00
3  2017-03-10 01:00:00
4  2017-03-10 01:00:00
```

...

expected:

```
0  2017-03-10 01:00:20
1  2017-03-10 01:00:40
2  2017-03-10 01:01:00
3  2017-03-10 01:00:20
4  2017-03-10 01:00:40
```

...

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Pandas - Add seconds from a column to datetime in other column*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081457/pandas-add-seconds-from-a-column-to-datetime-in-other-column)

Comment: @AlexandreB. - no, it is not this dupe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add timedeltas created by `np.arange` multiple by `20` with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
td = pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(1, len(dataframe) + 1) * 20, unit='s')
```

Or created by [`timedelta_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.timedelta_range.html):

```
td = pd.timedelta_range(0, periods=len(dataframe), freq='20s')
```

---

```
dataframe['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['date']) + td
print (dataframe)
                 date
0 2017-03-10 01:00:20
1 2017-03-10 01:00:40
2 2017-03-10 01:01:00
3 2017-03-10 01:01:20
4 2017-03-10 01:01:40
```