# How to add timedelta for each time seperately contain in one column of data frame using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a dataframe like this:

| action | application_id | interaction_time | notification_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | 1 | 4489200 | 79 | 3152 |
| F | 1 | 4388400 | 79 | 3633 |
| C | 0 | 4410000 | 78 | 655 |
| F | 0 | 4489200 | 72 | 6280 |

which *interaction_time* is in seconds, now I want to add a column to dataframe which is interation time add to especific time(like: 2021,9,21).

I used this code:

```
seconds=df["interaction_time"]
df['date'] =  timedelta(seconds=df["interaction_time"]) + datetime.datetime(2019,6,1)
```

Finally I get this error:

> unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: Series

how can I fixed it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Add seconds from a column to datetime in other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081457/pandas-add-seconds-from-a-column-to-datetime-in-other-column) <- in your case the date column can be replaced with the`datetime.datetime(2019,6,1)`

Comment: This may help too: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'action': ["F","F","C","F"],
                  'application_id': [1, 1,0,0],
                  'interaction_time': [4489200, 4388400,4410000,4489200],
                  'notification_id': [79, 79, 78, 72],
                  'user_id': [3152, 3633, 655, 6280]})

pd.to_timedelta(df['interaction_time'], unit='S') + datetime(2019,6,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
s = """action   application_id  interaction_time    notification_id user_id
F   1   4489200 79  3152
F   1   4388400 79  3633
C   0   4410000 78  655
F   0   4489200 72  6280"""
temp = [x.split('   ') for x in s.split('\n')]
data = temp[1:]
cols = temp[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
import datetime
base = datetime.datetime(2019,6,1)
pd.to_timedelta(df['interaction_time']+ ' S')+base
```

Output:

[image]